# Read Tab content in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, textview, findviewbyid

In my java code in Android Studio, I have a simple tab structure with below structure:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    ....>
    <LinearLayout
        ....>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            ....>
            <TextView
                ...
                android:text="tab0" />
            <TextView
                ...
                android:text="tab1" />
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            ...>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_0"
                android:text="content0"
                ..../>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_1"
                android:text="content1"                 
                ..../>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

In one part of my code, I need to read the TextVeiw contents.
While I can read the tab titles with below code, but I could not find a way to access the tab's content ( I can see the content on mobile's screen

```
...
TabWidget tab_widgets = tabHost.getTabWidget();
FrameLayout tab_contents = tabHost.getTabContentView();

for (int index = 0; index < tab_widgets.getChildCount(); index++) {

  //access tab's title: Works OK !!
  View v_title = 
    tab_widgets.getChildAt(index).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
  TextView tv_title = (TextView) v_title;

  //access tab's content: NOT working ??
  View v_content = 
    tab_contents.getChildAt(index).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
  TextView tv_content = (TextView) v_content; // It is always NULL
}
```

Is there any idea about this? how can I read the text inside tabs' body?

Comment: Obviously, TextViews can be accessed directly using their explicit id. But here, I want to access them inside a loop, 
e.g. "for all TextViews ...do... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line `tab_contents.getChildAt(index).findViewById(android.R.id.title);` needs some changes:

A. use your custom `id`, in this case `textView_0` or `textView_1`
make sure you use `R.id.` and not the `android.R.id`

B. use either getChildAt() or findViewById(), not both

like: `tab_contents.getChildAt(index)` or `tab_contents.findViewById()`

Comment: tab_contents.getChildAt(index), without findViewById worked! thanks! but I wonder why for the tab_widgets, the findViewById is required. I tested tab_widgets.getChildAt(index) alone, and it did not work. Do you know why?

Comment: @hamzee `TabWidget` returns a `Linearlayout` in return when get a child from it. cast it to a `ViewGroup`, then you will find your `Textview` as a child in it.